# Convert Resolutions depending on which Resolution the user is running

Tags: c#

Im making a Program which makes stuff Easier for a Game with fast Inputs. Since my Tool right now is only for 1920x1080 and i want to get it going for multiple Resolutions. Thats how i have it right now for 1920x1080.

```
              SetCursorPos(105, 640);
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
              sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
              SetCursorPos(274, 547);
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
              sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1560);
              sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_T);
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
              SetCursorPos(274, 547);
              sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1610);
              SetCursorPos(274, 547);
              sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1610);
              SetCursorPos(274, 547);
              sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
              SetCursorPos(960, 540);
```

I kinda want the Program detects the actual Screen Resolution and converts the Pixel Location from 1920x1080 to its needed Locations.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically...store your (x, y) coordinates as decimal numbers representing the "percentage" of the original resolution you developed them in.

For instance, your first point is (105, 640).  As a "percentage point", divide the x-coordinate by 1920, and the y-coordinate by 1080 to get (0.0546875,  0.5925925925925926).  This can be stored using the [PointF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pointf?view=netframework-4.8) structure.

Now you can use those decimal percentage numbers to get the desired equivalent point in any resolution by simply multiplying them by the width/height of the screen.

You can get the current screen resolution using [Screen.Bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Rectangle rc = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Scaling`.

You've coded for a fixed resultion of `1920x1080`. I.e. `1920` pixels width and `1080` pixels height.

If you need to scale this you can get the current screen resultion and then calculate the ratio.

Let's say the resolution is `640x480`. Then you'd calculate the `X` (or width) ratio with:

`640 / 1920 = 0.3333...`

and the `Y` (or height) ratio with:

`480 / 1080 = 0.4444...`

To scale you now multiply width and height with respective ratio:

`SetCursorPos(105 * 0.3333, 640 * 0.4444)`

In code it would look something like:

```
int currentX = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
int currentY = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

var xScale = currentX / 1920;
var yScale = currenty / 1080;

SetCursorPos(105 * xScale, 640 * yScale);
```

Comment: i see that SystemParameters is for WPF is there a good way for Windows Forms ?

Comment: You can use [Screen.Bounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen?view=netframework-4.8) as @Idle_Mind suggested.

Comment: i was not at home the last couple weeks. I tried to apply it to my Code and when i use the Action it will move my Cursor to the Right Bottom of my 2nd Screen. 
 https://pastebin.com/x0cZfhNh maybe i made a mistake here ?